# Function created as var doesn't have .name property. Why?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Today at a presentation about JS, we (students) were told that in JavaScript everything is an object. As an example, this code was provided:

```
// functions are objects
function aFunction(a, b) {
    // do something
};

console.log(aFunction.name); // aFunction
```

I've found this interesting and decided to try if the function declared as `var funcName = function(...` will behave the same way. It doesn't:

```
function aFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var bFunction = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

console.log(aFunction.name); // aFunction
console.log(bFunction.name); // empty string
```

Why?

Comment: "In JavaScript everything is an object" --- you have been misled.
`"cthulhu"` is not an object. `-4` is not an object. `true` is not an object. `undefined` is not an object.

Comment: @g.kertezh are you sure? try ```console.log("ctulhu".toUpperCase())```

Comment: In that case a new temporary object is created automatically. Try `var c = "cthulhu"; c.prop = 5; console.log(c.prop);` to see that you cannot assign properties to primitives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an unnamed function. Sometimes called an "anonymous" function or a "lambda".

```
function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If you want it named, you could do

```
var bFunction = function bFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

But that's a bit redundant, and if you wish for your function to be named, it's best to just write it as a named function

```
function bFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

bFunction;       //=> function bFunction(a,b) { ... }
bFunction.name;  //=> "bFunction"
```

---

As for the comments below, the not-so-obvious benefit of using named functions is they stacktrace better. That is, if you frequently use anonymous functions in your code, and an error occurs in one of them, the stacktrace will not be too informative.

Compare the anonymous function error

```
(function() { undefined.x; })()

//=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at <anonymous>:2:24
```

Vs the named function error

```
(function foo() { undefined.x; })()

//=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at foo (<anonymous>:2:28)
```

Notice how the named function stacktrace mentions `foo` which helps us identify the function that contains the bug.

Comment: Although if you use the same name for the variable as the function declaration, it's redundant. But something like `var x = function y(){}` might possibly make sense.

Comment: @Touffy I've found it makes sense to have them have the same name, since you reference it by  the variable name but the function name is used in e.g. stack traces.

Comment: No, @ryachza, it makes no sense because a function statement with a name will automatically create a local variable with that name, and will even "hoist" it up in the scope.

Comment: @Touffy I'm not sure I understand. For example, `var a = function test(x){ console.log('here'); }; test(0);` throws with `test is not defined`.

Comment: @ryachza yes. I fixed my previous comment a few minutes ago to say "function *statement*". Which is just like a function definition, except that it is not included in a larger statement, i.e. it starts with `function`. You are aware that `var test = function test(){}` would not do anything more than just `function test(){}`, right? that was my point.

Comment: @Touffy I understand and agree that those are equivalent and usually would be redundant, but I would expect there are cases where you would want to the names to be the same. This is certainly not the same case, but a usage I have seen: `var a = (function(){ return function test(x){ throw 'here'; }; })(); a(0);` where without the `test` the stack trace will show `anonymous`, and it is reasonable to want the name to match the variable. Other cases I think rely on the dynamic nature and scoping of JS and while *appear* to work the same, I think conceptually are not.

Comment: @ryachza yes I've seen that usage too and I guess we'll see it for a while until native ES6 `import` gets implemented. Note that it's pulling a function from an inner scope, which would be unable to create variables in the scope where the `var` is assigned.

Comment: @Touffy—that's a *function expression*, not a *function statement* (which is an extension to the language that has been implemented differently in different implementations and has varying behaviour, so avoid them). See also [*Block-Level Function Declarations Web Legacy Compatibility Semantics*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics).

Comment: @RobG Right, I should say *function declaration*. Which is a kind of statement… and so is an *expression statement*, and a function expression is an expression which can therefore be an expression statement…

Comment: @Touffy All I'm trying to show is that while `var a = function a(){}` and `var a = function(){}` *appear the same from most perspectives*, semantically they *are not the same* so eventually it could bite you if you assume they are identical. A contrived example: `var a = function(x){ if(x < 5) a(x + 1); }; var c = a; a = null; c(1);` will fail, but `function a(x)` will succeed.

Comment: @Touffy—a function expression can't be a statement, it must be part of a larger production that is a statement, e.g. you can't have just `function(){};`, there must be something else to complete the statement, which is why IIFEs are wrapped in `(...)` or preceded by `!` or similar tricks.

Comment: @ryachza I was never arguing about anonymous functions. Can we please agree that, no matter how many *different* cases you bring up, the case of `var a = function a(){}` is completely redundant?

Comment: @RobG actually, if you try `function (){}` as a standalone expression, you get "SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name." (in WebKit). So you see, I'm not the only one who calls those "statements" :p And named function expressions must be part of a larger statement only because if they aren't, then they're called a function statement with the extra semantics to go along. The grammar is the same.

Comment: The term "function statement" does not exist in any ECMAScript specification, therefore there is (strictly) no such thing. Developers are not authorities (trust me on that!), the correct error should be "Function **declarations** must have a name". Function expressions must be part of a larger statement because the specification requires them to be. If they have a name then the surround code defines whether they are a function declaration or function expression.

Comment: Adorable. All of you are so fricken adorable. /me throws bird seed

Comment: @Touffy No, because the example I gave last demonstrates an instance where `var a = function a()` and `var a = function()` do not have the same result. I agree that *from most perspectives* it is redundant, but that is not the same as "completely". The two `a`'s are fundamentally completely different things.

Comment: @Touffy The issue is that the `a` in `function a` is available when the function is *created*, but the `a` in `var a` is available when the function is *called*. Usually the distinction doesn't matter, but sometimes it does.

Comment: @RobG :D. Right, I've read the spec, it's clear that the proper term in it is "function declaration". It's also clear that "function statement", while not the consecrated term, can be interpreted as a synonym, because WebKit does it and because it's logical. And we agree that the difference between named function expressions and declarations is purely contextual.

Comment: @ryachza you keep dodging the point. I give up. Naomik sorry for cluttering your answer and probably spamming your notifications, but I don't eat or catch bird seed, throw me some new ChocolateError() please ;)

Comment: `if (lol) throw new ChocolateDonutError('more donut required');`

Answer (score 4):

That's because it's an anonymous function, it doesn't have a name. Anonymous functions calling the `name` property will return an empty string.

```
var bFunction = function bFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

alert(bFunction.name);
```

Comment: Well they *can* access the `name` property; there just isn't one set.

Comment: I don't mean to sound like I'm nagging, but your edit is also incorrect. It will return `""` (empty string), not `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. Learn something new every day

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you didn't assign a name to it.

```js
var bFunction = function bFunction(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

alert(bFunction.name); // changed to alert since it works better with the snippets
```